# Switching from Mac to Linux DE: Strategies for globally swapping <ctrl> modifier with <meta>?

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, desktop-environments

I'm switching from MacOs to Linux and exploring several popular Desktop Environments like KDE Plasma, Gnome & Pantheon, etc.

I find that the MacOS convention of using the `meta` key (aka the `command` key) as the "most common" keyboard shortcut modifier key for UI commands (like "Copy", "Paste", "New Window", etc) is far superior to the Linux/Windows convention of using `ctrl` instead.

Why?

1. The `meta` key is physically placed in a much easier-to-reach place on the vast majority of keyboards than `ctrl`, so that performing keyboard shortcuts (aka "chording") is far more ergonomically sound with `meta` than with `ctrl`. Repetitive Stress Injury from typing is a real problem, and difficult "chording" is one of the main culprits. Using `meta` as the common modifier improves this.
2. There are several very common traditional terminal/shell keyboard shortcuts that already use the `ctrl` key like `ctrl-c` which naturally conflict with the Linux DE convention of using `ctrl-c` for a globally-recognized UI "Copy" shortcut. This is aggravating. I gather most Linux terminal emulators offer "special" alternative keyboard shortcuts to perform normal things like "Copy" such as `shift-ctrl-c`. No bueno. This is annoying and breaks muscle memory.

**So I am looking for general strategies (or even specific tactics) of configuring a popular Linux Desktop Environment with the `ctrl` and `meta` modifier keys as somehow globally swapped for UI keyboard shortcuts**.

As on MacOS, I want typical UI shortcuts (like "Copy", "Paste", "New Window", etc) to use the `meta` modifier while the traditional shell shortcuts (like `ctrl-c`, `ctrl-d`, etc) should remain using the `ctrl` modifier.

The only option I've tried so far is to use a physical "programmable keyboard" which allows you to reprogram individual keys. This is a poor solution. It kinda-sorta solves problem number 1 above, but does not solve problem number 2.

Any general or specific advice on how to tackle this? I'm willing to try a completely new Linux Desktop Environment if it offers more flexibility in this regard. Tips on which DE might be best for this sort of thing, or tips on how to achieve this in any particular DE are also welcome.

Comment: This site is about single, specific, practical problems that can have single, specific, and practical solutions. Your question is not a bad question, it is just asking for suggestions, opinions, discussion, etc, and as such is not a good fit here. I recommend finding a forum where open and ongoing discussion is the purpose and goal.